# Search Keyword/Abbreviation in Internet Explorer 9

Tags: internet-explorer, shortcuts, search-engines, internet-explorer-9

In Chrome I rely heavily on search "keywords" as a shortcut for searching specific sites. For instance to search Google I quickly type `g some topic`, or to search youtube `yt funny video`, Wolfram Alpha `wa us dollar`.

How can I configure the same in Internet Explorer 9, if at all possible?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if keywords are possible, but I suggest to press the up arrow twice and then select an engine.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but having to use the arrow keys is slower obviously, and less comfortable.